# Can anyone help me put a blank image over a photo on a web site?

Tags: html, css

The client doesn't want the photo to be downloaded if it is right clicked on. I explained if someone wants the photo they can get it off the site but he wants to make it a bit more difficult for a novice user to download the image. Hence if you right click you will get the blank 'photo' instead of the actual photo underneath.

Comment: I remember Flickr used to do that. I am not sure they are using this metod anymore or not

Answer (score 5):

Use logic:

1. Put the image you want to protect as a background image in a <`div>` or other block level element
2. Put an `<img>` that is transparent over that image in the `<div>`. Make sure it covers the entire image/div

Answer (score 0):

A quick google has thrown this up for me, hope it can help you.

4) Prevent Downloads Using Tables: 'Right clicking' images is a fast shortcut to find, copy, and/or download images. For those that have their own website it is possible to prevent this action by placing images as a background to tables. The code is fairly simple in CSS, using the "background-image:url" style:

```
<table style="background-image:url('image.jpg');width:Wpx;height:Hpx"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
```

Another method might be,

5) Javascript Right Click Disable: Another measure to prevent right clicks on images is to use Javascript. These short scripts over-ride browser right clicks. Rather than recreate a script that has been widely published in various forms over the internet, I will leave it to the reader to search google for Javascript Disable Right Click. I will however mention that Javascript is client-side, and scripts such as these can not only effect the usability of a website, but can also readily be disabled by turning Javascript off.

I took the info above from this site --- http://www.naturefocused.com/articles/image-protection.html ---

People can just printscreen the image and put it in paint if they really wanted it though im afraid :(

Thanks,

Jack.

Comment: Why would you use a table rather than an img tag?

Comment: To prevent people right clicking and saving the image, as i said i took it from another site.

Comment: OK, but tables carry semantic data, you shouldn't use them as a container for anything but tabular data.

A plain div/span would work just as well. Or as **John Conde** said above, you could use an img tag — this would allow for adding alt text, etc. that would go along with the 'real' image.